# Maximum Data Length in a MySQL field

Tags: mysql

I m designing a new forum for My Company and i wanted to confirm that saving the forum posts in MySQL Database would be scalable and would it have good Performance ..?
The Posts may have characters around 400(may be i will limit to 400 Chars). If i save 400 Chars of text in a MySQL field, and the Table has 10 million rows, will it affect performance ..?
My Main constraint is performance. Can Please Someone Shed light on this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two data type to consider VARCHAR or TEXT

What datatype you decide on depends on

- How frequently you display it ?
- Total number of characters you store

TEXT and BLOB is stored off the table with the table just having a pointer to the location of the actual storage.

VARCHAR is stored inline with the table. VARCHAR is faster when the size is reasonable, the tradeoff of which would be faster depends upon your data and your hardware, you'd want to benchmark a realworld senerio with your data.

VARCHAR (stored inline) is usually faster IF the data is frequently retrieved (included by most queries). However, for a large volume of data that is not normally retrieved (that is, not referenced by any query), then it may be better to not have the data stored inline. There is an upper limit on the row size, for data stored inline.

When a table has TEXT or BLOB columns, the table can't be stored in memory. This means every query (which doesn't hit cache) has to access the file system - which is orders of magnitude slower than the memory.

If you post content is large use TEXT field but store the Text field in a seperate table which is only accessed when you actually need it. This way the original table can be stored in memory and will be much faster.

Think of it as separating the data into one "memory table" and one "file table". The reason for doing this is to avoid accessing of the filesystem except when neccessary (i.e. only when you need the text).

You can try (posts, post_text) or (post_details, posts) or something like that.